# Can I replace these left joins with a union or some other optimization?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize a query that returns the membership of objects in two groups.  Group "a" is a one-to-one link table (ie. object_id is a unique foreign key in group_a) and group "b" is one-to-many (object_id can have multiple entries in group_b).  Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
-- show objects and their membership w/ LEFT JOIN
SELECT DISTINCT o.name,
    a.object_id IS NOT NULL as in_group_a,
    b.object_id IS NOT NULL as in_group_b
FROM object o
LEFT JOIN group_a a ON (a.object_id = o.object_id)
LEFT JOIN group_b b ON (b.object_id = o.object_id)
WHERE a.object_id IS NOT NULL
OR b.object_id IS NOT NULL;
```

It returns something like this:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| name   | in_group_a | in_group_b |
+--------+------------+------------+
| Fred   |          1 |          0 |
| Barney |          1 |          1 |
| Betty  |          0 |          1 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

Note that Barney is in both groups but only one row is returned; this is critical.  I tried to rewrite this query with a union:

```
-- show objects and their membership w/ UNION
SELECT o.name, tmp.in_group_a, tmp.in_group_b
FROM ((
    SELECT a.object_id, 1 as in_group_a, 0 as in_group_b
    FROM group_a a
) UNION (
    SELECT b.object_id, 0 as in_group_a, 1 as in_group_b
    FROM group_b b
)) tmp
INNER JOIN object o ON (tmp.object_id = o.object_id);
```

This query is 10 times faster but I get multiple rows for objects in both groups:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| name   | in_group_a | in_group_b |
+--------+------------+------------+
| Fred   |          1 |          0 |
| Barney |          1 |          0 |
| Barney |          0 |          1 |
| Betty  |          0 |          1 |
+--------+------------+------------+
```

I'm guessing the original query is slow because it starts with the object table, which is large and most entries are not in either group.

**Is it possible to make the union query return the results I want, and if not is there another way to optimize this query?**

FYI, here are my simplified example tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE object (
    object_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (object_id)
);

CREATE TABLE group_a (
    object_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    UNIQUE KEY (object_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object (object_id)
);

CREATE TABLE group_b (
    group_b_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    object_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    description VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (group_b_id),
    KEY (object_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object (object_id)
);

INSERT INTO object VALUES (1, "Fred"), (2, "Barney"), (3, "Wilma"), (4, "Betty");
INSERT INTO group_a VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO group_b VALUES (1, 2, "a"), (2, 4, "a"), (3, 4, "b"), (4, 4, "c");
```

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT o.name, sum(tmp.in_group_a), sum(tmp.in_group_b) .... group by o.name` do this in your second query.

Comment: Hah! That was too simple to claim an answer eh? Not sure why that didn't occur to me... Anyway thank you, I will accept your answer as repeated by @Jason.

Comment: No needed I was just passing through here and saw your question and decided to help without an answer... I spend most of my time on stackoverflow rather than here :). Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jorge Campos is correct

```
SELECT o.name, sum(tmp.in_group_a), sum(tmp.in_group_b)
FROM ((
   SELECT a.object_id, 1 as in_group_a, 0 as in_group_b
   FROM group_a a
   ) UNION (
   SELECT b.object_id, 0 as in_group_a, 1 as in_group_b
   FROM group_b b
   )) tmp
INNER JOIN object o ON (tmp.object_id = o.object_id)
GROUP BY o.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be simpler and faster:

```
SELECT  name,
        EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM group_a WHERE object_id = o.object_id )
                         AS in_group_a,
        EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM group_b WHERE object_id = o.object_id )
                         AS in_group_b
    FROM object AS o
```

If necessary, tack on

```
    HAVING in_group_a
        OR in_group_b
```

Comment: Didn't know about EXISTS; I like that, it's more clear. However performance is interesting with my real data...  With a small LIMIT this is much faster, but as I page through the results with larger offsets, it quickly gets slower than the UNION query. The UNION query has consistent timing regardless of the limit or offset.  Very odd...

Comment: No need for `OFFSET` or `LIMIT` with `EXISTS`.  And your original question did not mention pagination.  What are you talking about?

Comment: Look at the example result with 3 rows (in the original question); this is just a toy version of my real dataset. In reality the query results are many thousands of rows long and thus I use LIMIT/OFFSET to fetch a page at a time. But that doesn't matter; returning all rows of my real data is much faster with the UNION than with the EXISTS method.